# Carcinogenicity of home coated cast iron pans

Tags: polymers, food-chemistry

Cast iron pans are a traditional cooking utensil and are becoming more and more popular in recent  years.

I myself switched from Teflon/ PFC pans to cast iron pans.
To use the pan they are normally coated with oil, which is baked in. For this mostly line seed oil is used, as it polymerizes well.

The normal procedure is explained in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLGSLCaksdY)

Now my question is how likely is it that this process produces carcinogenic substances like PAH (Polycyclic Aromatic Hydrocarbons) which are often associated with heating oil.

EDIT:

As matt_black pointed out, I am interested of the amount of these substances. And if food that is cooked in a freshly coated pan contains significant more, than a pan with other coatings. The next question would be of course if so, how long this increase can be detected after multiple uses.

Comment: This is the wrong question. The right question is whether there is any evidence that seasoned cast iron cookware contains *enough* nasties for anyone to notice (over and above what cooking itself produces). The dose makes the poison.

Comment: "Line seed" oil? Do you mean *linseed* oil? Note that food-grade linseed oil, AKA flax seed oil, is not considered toxic, but "boiled" linseed oil may be, particularly if it contains plasticizers and polymerization catalysts.